# nginx s3 gateway handshake failure

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl, amazon-s3

I am new to nginx and trying to setup a nginx proxy in front of an s3 bucket using [this repo](https://github.com/nginxinc/nginx-s3-gateway).

Based on the repo, my settings file (name --> my.settings) looks like -

```
S3_BUCKET_NAME=my-s3-bucket
S3_SERVER=s3.amazonaws.com
S3_REGION=us-east-1
S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID=myaccesskey
S3_SECRET_KEY=mysecretkey
S3_SERVER_PORT=443
S3_SERVER_PROTO=https
S3_STYLE=path
S3_DEBUG=true
AWS_SIGS_VERSION=4
```

I built the image as suggested in the repo using -

`docker build -f Dockerfile.oss -t nginx-oss-s3-gateway  .`

and when I run the image using - `docker run -p8080:80 --env-file ./my.settings nginx-oss-s3-gateway`

the image starts up fine as expected. I attempt to send a request to retrieve an object from the bucket - `curl -v http://localhost:8080/index.html` and I get back a HTTP 404. I look at nginx container that is running and see this -

```
2021/05/12 02:39:17 [error] 58#58: *1 peer closed connection in SSL handshake while SSL 
handshaking to upstream, client: 172.17.0.1, server: , request: "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1", 
upstream: "https://52.217.165.200:443/mys3bucket/index.html", host: "localhost:8080"
172.17.0.1 - - [12/May/2021:02:39:17 +0000] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 404 146 "-" "curl/7.64.1" "-"
2021/05/12 02:39:17 [info] 58#58: *1 client 172.17.0.1 closed keepalive connection
```

I tried adding `ssl_verify_client off;` to the nginx.conf and reloading the config, but that was not helpful.

I have a feeling this is because nginx is unable to verify aws s3 certificate? in which case, should I be importing the s3 cert to a trust store and pointing to nginx config?  I am trying to avoid certificate pinning by downloading a specific cert.

Any advice on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I've followed the exact same steps from the repository as you've mentioned. And I'm able to access my S3 bucket files. The only difference I see from your configuration is, the property

> S3_STYLE=path

Instead I used

> S3_STYLE=virtual

And I also believe this has nothing to do with `ssl_verify_client`. You're getting the `404` HTTP response & this means you're able to connect to the S3 server - no issues with the certificate validation. Either the URL you're trying to access is wrong or configuration is wrong.

Comment: I tried with `S3_STYLE` set to path and virtual individually, logging into container and with several combinations of S3 credentials too. It did not work. Is your bucket public?

Comment: @satya No. My bucket is private. 
BTW, those properties are environment variables. So, logging into the container and changing them might not work, as the service will be up and running already. You should try changing the variables in your `my.settings` file and rerun the container to make it work, I guess.